# What triggers execution of the second parameter to require() in the "Hello Dojo!" tutorial

Tags: javascript, function, dojo

I was working my way through the "Hello Dojo!" tutorial found [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/hello_dojo/index.html).

The primary logic for this tutorial is found as a function passed to the `require()` call in the header, but I can't figure out what triggers it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1 id ="greeting">Hello</h1>
 <!-- load Dojo -->
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js" 
  data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
  
 <script>
<!-- how is this calling!? --> 
  require([
   'dojo/dom',
   'dojo/dom-construct'
  ], function(dom,domConstruct) {
   var greetingNode = dom.byId('greeting');
   domConstruct.place('<em> Dojo!</em>', greetingNode);
   })
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I understand how the logic *within* that function is called - obtaining a reference to the `greeting` element and then appending an `em` node to it - but I can't figure out why/how the code inside the function is executed to begin with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have: `require(...)`

So you call `require` and pass it pass an array of strings and a function as arguments.

`require` (or a function it calls later) is responsible for calling the second argument.